# php strtotime "thursday after next"

Tags: php, strtotime

How do I use strtotime to give me the date for "thursday after next"

more so, the thursday after next week's thursday.

I know there is `next Thursday` but what about `next next Thursday`?

Initially I was thinking `+1 next Thursday` but I am really unsure

Comment: If in doubt, why not try yourself? And if everything fails, do `next thursday` first and then `+1 week`

Comment: @Pekka웃 I don't have a unit test set up, getting to that part of the application for iterative tests would be more time consuming than asking here, how do other people deal with that? my php environment is kind of poor

Comment: It's a one liner and I would trust a personal test over something I read on the internet any day.

Comment: Other people deal with it using DateTime and DateInterval objects, which makes life so much easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strtotime("next Thursday", strtotime("next Thursday"));
```

This will give you the next thurday relative to the next thursday

Comment: that is very clever, hadn't realized it could be used that way

Comment: [Yo Dawg](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/xzibit-yo-dawg), I heard you liked `next thursday` so I put a `next thursday` in your `next thursday`